# Character Gaps On Comic Conversation : 4

Tags: character-identification, traditional-characters, conversation

I am learning Chinese by reading different texts. I have some problems recognizing some characters in this older copy of a book (the Chinese character is sometimes too dark to distinguish strokes and scanning doesn't help). Here is the work that I have done so far. Thank you for any help finding the missing characters (**I do not need the translations**, per se but just seeing a clear copy of the character would be helpful). In some cases if I have a question on context I have presented those issues. There are multiple questions because I want to show the work in context. I could break these up into smaller questions but that would not be helpful to other learners (learning conversation) and would unnecessarily clog the website.

Title: (missing context)

> 哆啦 A 梦 ( I think this is supposed to sound-out "Doraemon" but other than A 梦 referencing a dream I am lost of the implied double meaning. )

I need some help identifying the missing characters (I can find translations once I can see the characters clearly):

Pane 1
( ? ➜ missing character )

> 是我: I'm here
>
> **（？）了你一（？）吧** :
>
> 哇一: Sound(surprise); wa yi!

Pane 2
( ? ➜ missing character )

> 你是谁：Who are you
>
> 从哪里来的：Where did you come from?
>
> 想神什么: （？）not sure of meaning

Pane 3
( ? ➜ missing character )

> 为。。。。。为什么会从这裡（？）出来：
>
> 一（？）問这么多叫我（？）么回（？）：

Pane 4
( ? ➜ missing character )

> （？）了！（？）而言之：
>
> 我是来（？）你（？）（？）苦（？）的：

[image: doraemon-1-4]

### UPDATE

Semaphore's answer so it's easier to find:

Title

哆啦A夢 is just a transcription of ドラえもん|Doraemon, there's no meaning to it.

Panel 1

是我: "It's me."

嚇了你一跳吧?: "Did I scare you?" (or more literally "I must have scared you, right?")

Missed characters are: 嚇, 跳

Panel 2

你是誰? 從哪裡來的?: your translations are fine here.

想幹什麼: "What do you want (to do)?"

Missed characters are: 幹

Panel 3

為... 為什麽會從這裡跑出來... "H-How did you come out of here..."

一次問我這麼多叫我怎麽回答?: "How do you expect me to answer so many questions in one go?"

Missed characters are: 跑, 次, 麽

Panel 4

算了! 總而言之, 我是來救你脫離苦海的: "Never mind (all that), basically I'm here to save you from your suffering."

Missed characters are: 算, 總, 救, 脫, 離, 海

Comment: Voting to reopen - The reason given for the off-topic votes seem incorrect. Although I ask for help with ~12 characters (out of 60+ characters), I did show all my of my prior effort. I think the question is valuable to new learners (like me) because it shows conversation in context. If seeking points I could have broken these into multiple questions but my goal is to learn to read/speak/write Mandarin, and I hope to help others do the same. Technology cannot answer the problem of understanding what is read, which is why this forum exists, right? Hope you will join me to reopen this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Title**

哆啦A夢 is just a transcription of [ドラえもん|Doraemon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doraemon), there's no meaning to it.

---

**Panel 1**

`是我`: "It's me."

`嚇了你一跳吧?`: "Did I scare you?" (or more literally "I must have scared you, right?")

Missed characters are: **`嚇`, `跳`**

---

**Panel 2**

`你是誰? 從哪裡來的?`: *your translations are fine here.*

`想幹什麼`: "What do you want (to do)?"

Missed characters are: **`幹`**

---

**Panel 3**

`為... 為什麽會從這裡跑出來...` "H-How did you come out of here..."

`一次問我這麼多叫我怎麽回答?`: "How do you expect me to answer so many questions in one go?"

Missed characters are: **`跑`, `次`, `麽`**

---

**Panel 4**

`算了! 總而言之, 我是來救你脫離苦海的`: "Never mind (all that), basically I'm here to save you from your suffering."

Missed characters are: **`算`, `總`, `救`, `脫`, `離`, `海`**

Comment: Doraemon is probably meant to be a plausible name, 銅鑼衛門.